# activemq how to get message from queue with special order

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have a queue that messages has properties name orderno
how can I fetch message from queue sorted by orderno

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is really the [resequencer enterprise integration pattern](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/Resequencer.html)

You can achieve that using Apache Camel, which is bundled with ActiveMQ.

What you need to do is to add the following to the ´camel.xml´ config file in ActiveMQ.

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:unordered"/>
    <resequence>
       <simple>in.header.orderno</simple>
       <to uri="activemq:queue:ordered" />
       <stream-config capacity="5000" timeout="4000"/>
    </resequence>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

Then just make sure that file is included inside your ActiveMQ config, such as activemq.xml:

```
<import resource="camel.xml"/>
```

Note that this setup will read messages in any order from the "unordered" queue, while your application should read the re-ordered from the "ordered" queue.