# ActiveMQ: How to resequence the messages in a queue with custom property

Tags: mule, mulesoft

We are using JMS in our project and messages are written to the JMS queue by various producers to the same queue at the same time. Hence, ordering is messed up. is there anyway that messages can be re-ordered within the queue before consumed by consumer(s)

For instance, producer A produced messages -> M1, M2, M3 (with custom header property as 1, 2, 3)
producer B produced messages -> M4, M5, M6 (with custom header property as 4, 5, 6).

Because of the race condition we are getting messages to the queue as M1, M4, M5, M2, M3, M6.

Can we reorder the messages in the desired sequence like: M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, M6 using custom header property?

Note: We are not using Java in our project. We are using Mulesoft for producing and consuming the messages to & from JMS.

I have seen [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833967/activemq-how-to-get-message-from-queue-with-special-order) which is similar to our problem, but the solution provided in the link is not clear or rather not working when I followed the steps.

Comment: What is causing the message to be sent out or order in the first place?

Comment: Also, what wasn't working when you used the solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833967/activemq-how-to-get-message-from-queue-with-special-order)?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no way to ensure that messages are sent in the proper order in the first place then [Camel's resequencer](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/resequence-eip.html) is a good solution. Here's a simple example:

```xml
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:unordered"/>
    <resequence>
      <simple>in.header.seqnum</simple>
      <to uri="activemq:queue:ordered" />
      <stream-config capacity="5000" timeout="4000"/>
    </resequence>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

This route will read messages from the `unordered` queue and then resequence them based on the message header `seqnum` and then send them to the `ordered` queue. Therefore your application should read the re-ordered messages from the `ordered` queue.

The [Camel documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/resequence-eip.html) is pretty thorough so you should reference it for additional details.

Comment: >> I have already seen this solution in another post and shared the link in my initial post. It is not working when I followed the steps.

Comment: That's why I asked what wasn't working in the comment above. Do you see any errors? Are you using the right message header (i.e. `seqnum` in the example I provided)? If you don't explain why/how it's not working how can you expect to get additional help?

Comment: Sorry Justin for not being clear. I have made sure that I have added below camel context in my camel.xml file. <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <!-- You can use Spring XML syntax to define the routes here using the <route> element -->        
 <route>
  <from uri="activemq:queue:SampleQ1"/>
  <resequence>
   <simple>in.header.GroupID</simple>
   <to uri="activemq:queue:SampleQ12" />
   <stream-config capacity="5000" timeout="4000"/>
  </resequence>
 </route>
</camelContext>

Comment: and also I have added <import resource="camel.xml"/> in the activemq.xml file. when I now produced messages to the SampleQ1 but I don't see SampleQ12 getting created and messages were resequenced.

Comment: Where did you put your `camel.xml`? How are you sending the messages to `SampleQ1`? Can you share that code?

Comment: Also, you said that "messages **were** resequenced". Did you actually mean that they **weren't** resequenced? Please clarify.

Comment: I have camel.xml file in the following location ..\apache-activemq-5.15.10\examples\conf and I have added <import resource="camel.xml"/> in the activemq.xml which is located in the same location as camel.xml. please find the snippet of activemq.xml below:<beans
  <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" useJmx="false"> 
    <transportConnectors>
      <transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:61616"/>      
      <transportConnector uri="stomp://localhost:61613"/>
    </transportConnectors>    
  </broker>
  <import resource="camel.xml"/>  
</beans> I have added

Comment: I am using mule api to write messages to SampleQ1. this comments section is not allowing me to add complete code. Hence, I am sharing in bits and pieces. <flow name="jms_connectivity_pocFlow1">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/jmssend" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
        <set-payload value="#[payload]" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="Set Payload"/>

Comment: <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
 "GroupId":payload.GroupId
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <set-variable variableName="GroupId" value="#[dw('payload.GroupId')]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
            <add-message-property key="GroupID" value="#[dw('payload.GroupId')]"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>

Comment: <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="SampleQ1" connector-ref="Active_MQ"  doc:name="JMS">        
        </jms:outbound-endpoint>
        <logger message="Written to the queue : #[flowVars.GroupId]" level="INFO" doc:name="Copy_of_Logger"/>
    </flow>

Comment: Yes, I meant that the messages weren't resequenced.